# VScode Source Control Failing on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've been getting the following error from the source control plugin on VSCode "Extension host terminated unexpectedly".

If I check the logs I see the following info: "EMFILE too many open files."

I've already tried a few things like:

1. Remove and install VSCode again.
2. Increase the number of opened files on Ubuntu.
3. Install Watchmen

Unfortunately, none of this solved the problem... Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I can't help you, but you should post just how many files it does have open, and check that against the ulimit.

Comment: So I wasn't able to fix the issue on VSCode but a friend told me about VSCodium which kinda solved my problem... So now I use VSCodium instead and it's pretty much the same thing.